# kubernetes: Could not delete innodb cluster PODs forcefully

Tags: windows, kubernetes, mysql-cluster

PODs could not be deleted:

> kubectl get all

```
NAME              READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mycluster-0   0/2     Terminating   0          15h
pod/mycluster-1   0/2     Terminating   0          15h
pod/mycluster-2   0/2     Terminating   0          15h
```

> kubectl delete --force --all pods

```
Warning: Immediate deletion does not wait for confirmation that the running resource has been terminated. The resource may continue to run on the cluster indefinitely.
pod "mycluster-0" force deleted
pod "mycluster-1" force deleted
pod "mycluster-2" force deleted
```

> kubectl get all

```
NAME              READY   STATUS        RESTARTS   AGE
pod/mycluster-0   0/2     Terminating   0          16h
pod/mycluster-1   0/2     Terminating   0          16h
pod/mycluster-2   0/2     Terminating   0          16h
```

Terminating, not terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clean the pods you need to delete their deployments namespace.

First discover the existing deployments by running the below command:

```
$ kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

Delete the deployment by running:

```
$ kubectl delete deployment <NAME>
```

Then all corresponding pods of deployment will terminate by itself.

You can also try removing the finalizers in the pod by running below command:

```
kubectl patch pod <pod-name> -p '{"metadata":{"finalizers":null}}'
```

This syntax is used to terminate the pod that is stuck in your case.